# PHP XML from a URL Parsing to get a count of elements

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to process some XML output from a website API and simply get a count of the responses.  For some reason I am stuck.

XML Data
https://zkillboard.com/api/losses/allianceID/99005942/no-items/no-attackers/shipTypeID/609/pastSeconds/604800/xml/

What I would like to do is have PHP parse the XML via its URL and return a count of the `<row>` elements it returns,  say '8'    I don't know why I am having such difficulty with this.

I have tried a few of the suggestions on here but I am getting something wrong. I was working with this snippet with no luck.

```
    <?php
$url='https://zkillboard.com/api/losses/allianceID/99005942/no-items/no-attackers/shipTypeID/609/pastSeconds/604800/xml/';
$elem=new SimpleXMLElement($url, NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($elem as $rowset)
  {
  printf("%s has %d children.<br>", $rowset['kills'], $rowset->count());
  }

?>
```

It outputs:

```
has 0 children.
has 1 children.
has 0 children.
```

There does not appear to be 3 'rowsets' so not sure why this is iterating 3 times and the count is off.

Here is the XML

```
<eveapi version="2" zkbapi="1">
<currentTime>2016-02-03 13:26:55</currentTime>
<result>
<rowset name="kills" key="killID" columns="killID,solarSystemID,killTime,moonID">
<row killID="51763242" solarSystemID="30003951" killTime="2016-02-01 21:25:35" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="1737017947" characterName="Ma Tun" corporationID="916251988" corporationName="Lonetrek Blacksoul Federation" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="1975" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51747433" solarSystemID="30004754" killTime="2016-01-31 23:40:49" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="94366852" characterName="Bacon forAllah" corporationID="1102238026" corporationName="LazyBoyz Band of Recreational Flyers" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="2490" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51706013" solarSystemID="30004616" killTime="2016-01-30 16:11:14" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="93328027" characterName="GoginCZ" corporationID="803493697" corporationName="Bohemian Veterans" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="3790" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51704220" solarSystemID="30004755" killTime="2016-01-30 14:42:09" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="1891723276" characterName="Taur Kizandor" corporationID="728517421" corporationName="0.0 Massive Dynamic" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="1286" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51687964" solarSystemID="30004023" killTime="2016-01-29 20:44:28" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="94272496" characterName="Ding Bang Oww" corporationID="916251988" corporationName="Lonetrek Blacksoul Federation" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="2587" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51663835" solarSystemID="30004710" killTime="2016-01-28 15:03:36" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="94044078" characterName="Lortar Ogarr" corporationID="872886764" corporationName="Exanimo Inc" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="1308" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51656679" solarSystemID="30004738" killTime="2016-01-28 01:43:19" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="1891723276" characterName="Taur Kizandor" corporationID="728517421" corporationName="0.0 Massive Dynamic" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="1540" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
<row killID="51653821" solarSystemID="30004019" killTime="2016-01-27 22:32:50" moonID="0">
<victim characterID="90345974" characterName="Serrit Kaldan" corporationID="98079566" corporationName="101st Cliffdiving Regiment" allianceID="99005942" allianceName="Northern Army" factionID="0" factionName="" damageTaken="2397" shipTypeID="609"/>
</row>
</rowset>
</result>
<cachedUntil>2016-02-03 14:26:55</cachedUntil>
</eveapi>
```

Comment: "getting something wrong" is just not useful as a description. And: please post a valid part of the XML.

Comment: updated the original post

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.count.php

Comment: oh wow that is exactly the code I used if you read the above.  It is not working

Comment: is it? `$elem`vs. `$xml`. Basic debugging. see my comment above about "not working". This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Its also not a snark site.  If you want to go to 4chan go.    I asked for help debugging as its not working correctly.  I have updated the OP.

Comment: learn http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and avoid discussions like these. Path to `<row>`: /eveapi/result/rowset/row. If you indent your XML, this becomes pretty obvious. `$elem->result->rowset->row->count()`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried creating an instance by using

```
$elem=new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);
```

The third parameter tells to constructor, that $data (first parameter) is an URL instead of string containing XML.

Then you can print number of `row` elements by

```
print "Number of rows: " . $elem->result->rowset->row->count();
```

Comment: I tried the below...  there is the output.  am I parsing the elements wrong?  All I really want to do is get a count of the <row> elements under <rowset>

Thanks



<?php
$xml='https://zkillboard.com/api/losses/allianceID/99005942/no-items/no-attackers/shipTypeID/609/pastSeconds/604800/xml/';
$elem=new SimpleXMLElement($xml, 0 , true);
foreach ($elem as $rowset)
  {
  printf("%s has %d kill<br>", $rowset['killID'], $rowset->count());
  }
?>



Output:

has 0 kill
has 1 kill
has 0 kill

Comment: Your result has pretty easy explanation - you're iterating through children of document element (which is `eveapi`). And it has 3 children - first (`currentTime`) doesn't have any other children, second (`result`) has just 1 child (`rowset`) and third (`cachedUntil`) doesn't have any children too. If you need just number of row element within `result-rowset` use `$elem->result->rowset->row->count()`

Comment: @MilanTomeš You should edit that into your answer, since it is the solution.